# How to delete duplicate rows in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query, which I saw from another stackoverflow question but I am getting error.

```
delete from mytable
 where myid not in (
    select max(myid)
      from mytable
group by myid2)
```

Error:

> #1093 - Table 'mytable' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Edit 2:

I also tried this query:

```
delete from mytable
 where myid in (
    SELECT
    myid, COUNT(*)
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY
    myid2
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1)
```

And got this error:

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  You have `max(myid)` and `group by myid`.  This will delete no rows.

Comment: I will try that. I changed myid in group by to myid2 (they are different id, and contain same duplicate rows). But I sitll get the same error

Comment: @GordonLinoff .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you need to use a `JOIN` for this purpose.  I assume you mean something like this:

```
delete t
   from mytable t left join
        (select max(myid) as myid
         from mytable
         group by myid2
        ) tt
        on t.myid = tt.myid
   where tt.myid is null;
```

Where `?` is whatever you really want to group by.  Your version will not delete anything because the `group by` and `max()` use the same column.

Comment: I will try that. I changed `myid` in group by to `myid2` (they are different id, and contain same duplicate rows). But I sitll get the same error

Comment: I am getting this error `Unexpected keyword. (near "join" at position 9)`

Comment: @johndoe . . . That was a typo.